# What do the samples returned from Wave_read.readframes(n) represent?

Tags: python, wav

After some research I came across the wave and struct modules and how they can be used to look at audio samples together like so:

```
import wave, struct

song = wave.open('asymmetry.wav', 'rb')
print song.getparams()
length = song.getnframes()
values = []
for x in range(length):
    string = song.readframes(1)
    sample = struct.unpack('hh', string)
    values.append(sample)
```

This leaves me with a long list of sample values. I just want to know what those represent, whether it's amplitudes or frequencies or something else I don't know about.

Comment: Youtube don't eat it. Search python libs(pyaudio,audiofile,deflauce etc).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

`wave_read.readframes(n)`
Reads and returns at most `n` frames of audio, as a string of bytes.

Another reference:
https://www.cameronmacleod.com/blog/reading-wave-python